# <logic:messagesPresent> tag in Struts1 not looping through multiple errors in Action Messages

Tags: validation, jsp, struts, struts-1

I have a field in a bean that is failing 2 validations, as such 2 messages are being inserted in `ActionMessages` with the following command:

```
validationErrors.add("field1", new ActionMessage("Phone number is greater than 10 digits", false));
validationErrors.add("field1", new ActionMessage("Phone number has invalid characters", false));
```

Although I see the errors in the `ActionMessages` object (by setting a breakpoint in the debugger), only the first one gets displayed in my JSP, where I have:

```
<logic:messagesPresent message="true">
    <html:messages id="message" property="field1" message="true">
        <logic:present name="message">
            <c:out value="${message}"/>
        </logic:present>
    </html:messages>
</logic:messagesPresent>
```

Why is only the first message displayed, when `<html:messages>` should loop through all the messages where the property is `"field1"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out my issue and it had to do with how I am creating the new ActionMessage.

When you use:

```
public ActionMessage(<error message>, false)
```

While it allows you to display a literal value by using the `<html:messages>` tag in conjunction with either a `<bean:write>` or `<c:out>`, it won't iterate over multiple messages for a given property, why I don't know.

I tested and found that if I use a resource bundle and create the ActionMessage with a standard:

```
public ActionMessage(<key in resource bundle>)
```

I am able to display multiple messages for a single property.

Unfortunately, because I am using hibernate validator I don't want to use a resource bundle and struts to replace the values (would rather have the hibernate validator annotation replace values) and will likely just display a single message at a time for now.

Answer (score 0):

Struts [`<logic:messagesPresent>` tag](http://people.apache.org/%7Egermuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/logic/messagesPresent.html) checks that the messages exist on the current request.

Messages are found in the request under the key `Globals.MESSAGE_KEY`. If you use attribute `message` only messages are checked.

> By default the tag will retrieve the request scope bean it will
> iterate over from the `Globals.ERROR_KEY` constant string, but if this
> attribute is set to `true` the request scope bean will be retrieved
> from the `Globals.MESSAGE_KEY` constant string. Also if this is set to
> `true`, any value assigned to the name attribute will be ignored.

The [`<html:messages>` tag](http://people.apache.org/%7Egermuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/html/messages.html) is used to display the messages if specified attribute `message` is `true`.

Now you have used a `property` attribute that filters messages for the given property.

> Name of the property for which messages should be displayed. If not
> specified, all messages (regardless of `property`) are displayed.

If you have only one message with the `field1` property, then only one message will be displayed.

Look here how can you use action messages object

```
ActionMessages messages = new ActionMessages();
messages.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("error.common.field1.required");
saveMessages(request, messages); // storing messages as request attributes
```

**Properties file:**

```
error.common.field1.required = Field1 is required.
```

And display messages

```
<logic:messagesPresent message="true">
   <html:messages id="message" message="true">
     <bean:write name="message"/><br/>
   </html:messages>
</logic:messagesPresent>
```

It will loop all massages under the global message key. If you want to use custom key you can use it with the parameter of `ActionMessage`

```
messages.add("field1", new ActionMessage("error.common.field1.required");
```

to retrieve the message

```
<logic:messagesPresent message="true">
   <html:messages id="message" property="field1" message="true">
     <bean:write name="message"/><br/>
   </html:messages>
</logic:messagesPresent>
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, upon reading your response I reread my original question and cleaned it up to make it more clear.  I think the difference is that I am not using a resource bundle for these messages.